# Error in post method in laravel on hosting

Tags: laravel, hosting

The data is shown normal, it can be updated and everything, but when saving a record it is not saved and it shows me this error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public function store(Request $request, Cuenta $cuenta){
    $cuenta->id_cliente = $request->select_cliente;
    $cuenta->id_plan = $request->select_plan;
    $cuenta->id_plan_cuotas = $request->select_cuota;
    $cuenta->tipo_cuota = $request->select_tipo_cuota;
    $cuenta->id_agente = $request->select_agente;

    $cuenta->save();


    $data = DB::select("call change_status_create_cuotas(?, ?, ?)",array($request->select_cuota, $request->select_tipo_cuota ,$request->select_cliente));
    return redirect()->route('cuentas.index');
}
```

This is code to save the data, in the localhost it works correctly, but in the hosting it does not leave anything.

Comment: An HTTP 500 error is a general error; you'll need to check your logs to see the specific error message. Check `storage/logs/laravel.log`, and if there's nothing there, check your server logs (nginx, apache, etc.)

Comment: I checked the log file and found that there was an error in the primary keys, so I checked the database and realized that when I exported it I didn't put the autoincrements. Thanks.